# Is there a way to create an virtual table that would be compared to one after editing?

Tags: sql, eclipse, postgresql, validation, groovy

I have a table [contractor c] in which only one field [tin] may be edited. If the user tries to change data in other field it shall not be updated. Was wondering if making a view of the c before editing and then comparing the view with edited table is a good idea. But that would require two scripts- before and after update.
I could also make a validation on every single field except tin, but there is 'a lot' of fields.
Looking for the best and most optimal way to approach this task.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking about `sql` & `groovy` ? are you talking about the table in database? or about some UI element? please be more specific in your question and add details.

Comment: So I'm guessing that's an UI element build with fields from table in database (like address, name, tin, email etc.). User can either enter the preview or edit. When he enters edition it's supposed not to allow him to change any other field than tin.
From what I know some things are better done in sql, some using groovy and some using groovy based on select.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  There are many ways to do what you describe.  "Views" are not one of them.  In SQL, a **view** is a stored query.  It does not store values.  That is definitely not going to help, because the view changes with the underlying tables.

If only one column can be updated, then one method is to implement a trigger that checks the before- and after- versions of the record and only allows updates when no other fields change.

You can start learning about triggers in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

An alternative mechanism is to make the table unupdatable *except* for `update` permissions on a single column.  You can learn about permissions in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html).

If for some reason you wanted to do all the work in the application, then transactions might come into use.  You would not commit the transaction until the update meets your requirement.  Transactions are explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll check documentation you've linked and see what would work the best.